# How do I apply the decay factor in VaR (Value at Risk) using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variance/co-variance matrix calculated for 4 assets:

```
covariaances

Symbol                                        
AAPL    0.000617  0.000124  0.000197  0.000290
DE      0.000124  0.000928  0.000144  0.000191
IBM     0.000197  0.000144  0.000570  0.000244
MSFT    0.000290  0.000191  0.000244  0.000723
```

I am using a 153 day sample.  I need to apply a 97% decay factor.  The problem I am having is figuring out how to apply the factor and to exactly what variable.  Initially I thought it was returns but that can't be write as the more days I add the closer the total VaR number goes to zero (that code is at the end of this question for reference)

An extraction of my original DataFrame is below:

```
df.head()
Out[6]: 
        Date Symbol  ClosingPrice    Weight
0 2016-01-19   AAPL     93.905926  0.000694
1 2016-01-20   AAPL     91.860645  0.000694
2 2016-01-21   AAPL     93.355274  0.000694
3 2016-01-22   AAPL     96.728020  0.000694
4 2016-01-25   AAPL     97.553999  0.000694

df.tail()
Out[7]: 
          Date Symbol  ClosingPrice   Weight
603 2016-08-17   MSFT         57.23  0.00009
604 2016-08-18   MSFT         57.27  0.00009
605 2016-08-19   MSFT         57.20  0.00009
606 2016-08-22   MSFT         57.26  0.00009
607 2016-08-23   MSFT         57.85  0.00009
```

The weight column is the percent that the particular asset is of the entire gross market value

my complete code is below (in case it helps)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
from scipy.stats import norm
import datetime as dt

Days = 3
Value=592e6 # $1,000,000
CI=0.9975 # set the confidence interval
decay = 0.97
df=pd.read_csv('CloseWeightsmini.csv')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#df=df[df['Date'] > '2016-01-14']
df=df.drop_duplicates(['Date','Symbol'], keep='first')
df2=df.iloc[:,0:3].pivot('Date', 'Symbol', 'ClosingPrice')
df3=df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates().set_index('Symbol')
df4=df.iloc[:,[1,3]].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
tickers=df4['Symbol']
numbers=len(tickers)
data=df2

ret=data/data.shift(1)-1 # calculate the simple returns


ret.fillna(0)
ret.mean()*Days #normalizes the returns over specified days
covariances=ret.cov()*Days #gives the covariance of returns over specified days
variances=np.diag(covariances) #extracts variances of the individual shares from covariance matrix
volatility=np.sqrt(variances) #gives standard deviation
weights=(df4['Weight'])

Pf_ret=np.sum(ret.mean()*(weights))*Days #Portfolio return

Pf_variance=np.dot(weights,np.dot(ret.cov()*Days,weights)) #Portfolio variance
Pf_volatility=np.sqrt(Pf_variance) #Portfolio standard deviation

USDvariance=np.square(Value)*Pf_variance
USDvolatility=np.sqrt(USDvariance)

covariance_asset_portfolio=np.dot(weights.T,covariances)
covUSD=np.multiply(covariance_asset_portfolio,Value)
beta=np.divide(covariance_asset_portfolio,Pf_variance)
fwrite=open("VAR.csv","w")
def VaR():
    # this code calculates Portfolio Value-at-risk (Pf_VaR) in USD-terms and Individual Value-at-risk (IndividualVaR) of shares in portfolio.  
    Pf_VaR=norm.ppf(CI)*USDvolatility
    IndividualVaR=np.multiply(volatility,Value*weights)*norm.ppf(CI)
    IndividualVaR = [ '$%.2f' % elem for elem in IndividualVaR ]
    fwrite.write('Portfolio VaR: ')
    fwrite.write(str(Pf_VaR) + "\n")
    print(Pf_VaR)

    for i in range (min(len(tickers), len(IndividualVaR))):
        fwrite.write("Individual Var:  ")
        fwrite.write(tickers[i]+"   ")
        fwrite.write(IndividualVaR[i] + "\n")

VaR() #call the function to get portfolio VaR and Individual VaR in USD-terms

def marginal_component_VaR():
     # this code calculates Marginal Value-at-risk in USD-terms and Component Value-at-risk of shares in portfolio. 
    marginalVaR=np.divide(covUSD,USDvolatility)*norm.ppf(CI)
    componentVaR=np.multiply(weights,beta)*USDvolatility*norm.ppf(CI)
    marginalVaR = [ '%.5f' % elem for elem in marginalVaR ]
    componentVaR=[ '$%.2f' % elem for elem in componentVaR ]

    for i in range (min(len(tickers), len(marginalVaR))):
        fwrite.write("Marginal Var:  ")
        fwrite.write(tickers[i]+"   ")
        fwrite.write(marginalVaR[i] + "\n")

    for i in range (min(len(tickers), len(componentVaR))):
        fwrite.write("Component Var:  ")
        fwrite.write(tickers[i]+"   ")
        fwrite.write(componentVaR[i] + "\n")

marginal_component_VaR() #call the function 
datasave=data.tail(153)
datasave.to_csv('stockprice2.csv')
```

i tried this but don't think I am implementing the factor correctly (conceptually and pragmatically)

```
ret=data/data.shift(1)-1 # calculate the simple returns
retFac = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j : decay**(i), ret.values.shape)[::-1]
ret=ret*retFac

ret['ret_decay'] = retFac[:,0]
```

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: A 97% decay factor over what period of time?

Comment: 100% of today's, 97% of yesterdays, 0.97^2) the day before that and so on. . .153 days in total, but may be more or less.  I have the code to calculate the factor (retFac) just not sure how to apply it.  I think I am supposed to weight the variance, but I am not quite sure how to do this

Comment: @John Why wouldn't you perform operation with original dataframe: `today = pd.to_datetime('2016-08-31'); df.ClosingPrice *= 0.97 ** (today - df.Date).dt.days`? Or just make copy if you need it.

Comment: I think I am looking to apply the decay factor on normalized returns and not prices, I am trying to figure that part out . . .exactly what does the decay factor apply too?.  I also need to use trading days (observations) rather than calendar days from today.